# golang/crypto: DSS key no longer works

Tags: go, ssh, sftp, dsa

I'm using an SFTP with my service to download some files which are integral to our functionality.

After [this commit](https://github.com/golang/crypto/commit/88e95fbb56610f02dbc78ebc3b207bec8cf56b86#diff-aab72d98d6b840106cb1ffed0390f951) to the `golang/x/crypto` packgae, my key no longer works.

Considering the commit message, `ssh: reject unsupported DSA key sizes`, it would seem that the key now breaks that new validation. However, the error I get is `ssh: no key found`.

The key is read from `$ ssh-keyscan euftp.morningstar.com`, so I'm puzzled if it's not valid.

This is the public DSS / DSA key I'm using:

```
euftp.morningstar.com ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAAEBAJgHdansQ87KIX8tEj8U0tEIUpU0UJ98V/A8hF+Fv/F2zX7yq7zOQrg+RKd2M4OJPaYZ+KVF4o5XmGe3cGNggBZTUaIhYIVhjRw4EAjyf/CmLDso1sWy48GUXoapBVbzMxVzs4xkeHN4UJgsHvANKo5PFIC/A4hNPy9AxbqlS2h4pg3/Ritzz70y0wP6f6y3h60MK87UEayGms6FbdYmGf/DGXljRsVrEBZYyrEj7oPEUpH07y2+XeYRpyeG+2llstMRF6xuaq088zLT//q3cv+jprTNT9T+iVI2Q2diy69DQeOO8mp2YZgTrGP9t048W7/Ps1zEEL1uj/dWS3XG6McAAAAVAIQP+o3wCWe+twgSY3Qk0SIvH1ndAAABAHwQNTLdSr0HDhBnVi3EPx1+PdKeHGt5L+jauZO3pq/8Ja4vNX26sraeEWjeLbW5ipEzkXlvX3VG+PCOs6XtNI6HojC3T0lulwLqEH5jBtAAyAuP2Ec3lYw9PldGGzsSx7gW6BaUKVqQnQW+27Kxtcyh1ti80dz/jI1//iapV5HAyrOjeHKjSdrsSeJ6VJ6eTDWDDcpChzhhdp9L66C90emv6rNNjwO/YVzUaNgaISgnCVnoQoHNj23rc8ihumMcDoNmh+u4xXcfS3HLGaNByS4GwMGMDR5KYFK2CbL5BLUW7HPTSTORvhsU+28rkeOsQCfZiReRC8re8Hwep5qNrkkAAAEACCrGotD2kLVfEbEpFrvqvzVkAolBet11rrPBxOS+UvL1UK5nsO4i179iSrFrl9DH9D1U4qVjGmKZxhPPtWRLSf/8h7bCYzcgdmK+U7o6XbUoHGnvW7pGktrMXSlGkF37Rk4OV9zTmUDb/kPxqGAl1BxNXcU7XDCSoZLXzPMyzTT+ezgfaSzGMWZTXKJFXHNffo8e8h+DijQiLOhVUU8RYbAh0C7dZgu4l9+lgO+yX711IFixoeuf8ahET90/IogLnMsQevsrzQzb6aXXe2daIDIHxPWJ1m+erxCHKZoCWAQeG5MSMjvSQup70WGiDa/6AXEldlcFf96Y8npLiO9Y4A==
```

Regardless of what the core issue is (although I really want to know), I'm in dire need of a solution. How can I create SSH connections again for this key?

Comment: I think you're going to have to use a patched version of the ssh package if you want it to continue to work with that server. It sounds like it's using a key that outside of the spec, so it only worked by accident before. Note that even a default openssh client refuses to connect to that server.

Comment: Oh... that's too bad. Would I have to make the patch myself, or do you think there's something I can use?

Comment: You can use an older checkout of that package, or you can patch it yourself.